# Dojo: dijit/form/VerticalSlider: Does not work in IE8 IE9 IE10

Tags: dojo

On this page is a demo of sliders in dojo:
https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/sliders/demos/rules.html

The horizontal slider on this page works on IE8 until Edge as expected.
But the vertical slider works in Edge only. In IE less Edge the height of the dijitSliderBar seems to be 0 - the thumb is fix and not dragable.

The demo was build with dojo 1.10 - but in the current version 1.12.2 the problem is still there. Does somebody has any idea to fix the problem?

Comment: I checked it in IE 11 and it works just fine. You can report a bug at [Dojo Bug Tracker](https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/)

Comment: Thanks for your tip. I've reported a bug in https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/18999#ticket